# Keep getting errors with Tensorflow python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

class ModelClass:
    """ used for getting all the juicy payloads and making them """

    def __init__(self, model=None):
        if not model:
            self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=256, output_dim=128),
                                              tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128),
                                              tf.keras.layers.Dense(
                                                  1, activation='sigmoid')
                                              ])
            self.model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

        else:
            self.model = model
    def train(self):
            payload_list = open('./sqli_tester/all.txt', 'r').readlines()
            seeds = np.random.randint(0,high=2**32-1, size=(500, 1), dtype=np.int64)
            labels = [random.choice(payload_list) for _ in range(500)]
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((seeds, labels))
            train_dataset = dataset.take(80)
            val_dataset = dataset.skip(80)
            print(train_dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
            #inputs = tf.Tensor(1,(), dtype=tf.int64)
            #train_dataset = tf.constant(train_dataset).reshape(-1,1)
            history = self.model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=val_dataset, validation_split=0.1)
            # self.model.save('model.h5')
            return self.model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    modelc = ModelClass()
    modelc.train()
```

I keep getting the error: `Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (1, 128)` can anyone help me please? I use the model for other code like predicting data. If it would be possible to get an explanation on why this is happening and how to fix it in the future that would be amazing. Thank you. The warning I get with tensorflow is `WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, None) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.float32, name='embedding_input'), name='embedding_input', description="created by layer 'embedding_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (1,).`

Comment: This kind of error means that the model was trained with different input shape than when you are calling the model to make a prediction. The first error says it expects 3 dimensions but it received `[1,128]` which is 2 dimensions.

Comment: @c3ald, Inputs needs to be reshaped to [samples, time steps, features] like `train_dataset=np.reshape(train_dataset, (train_dataset.shape[0], 1, train_dataset.shape[1])`. Thank you!